# How to properly implement the Modified Gram-Schmidt Algorithm in R Code?

Tags: r, math, matrix, linear-algebra

For context, this is the algorithm I am trying to replicate in R:
[image]

This is the code I have implemented.

```
X = matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = T)

txtMGS <- function(A){
  Q <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))
  R <- matrix(0, nrow = ncol(A), ncol = ncol(A))
  for(i in 1:ncol(A)){
    v <- A[,i, drop = F]
  }
  for(i in 1:ncol(A)){
    R[i,i] <- sqrt(sum(v^2))
    Q[,i] <- v / R[i,i]
    for(j in i + 1:ncol(A)){
      R[i,j] <- sum(Q[,i] * v)
      v <- v - R[i, j] * Q[,i]
    }
  }
  QR <- list(Q = Q, R = R)
  
  return(QR)
}

txtMGS(X)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = sum(Q[, i] * v)) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure j goes from i+1 to n? Seems wrong to me, or you need to prevent j from going above n, which occurs when i = n.

Comment: I added parentheses around i+1, but I am still receiving the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, that was one issue. But there's still the problem of j going from n+1 to n when i=n.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, I changed the i + 1  to just i and it produced the wrong answer, but at least there's no error now. I'm not sure why the algorithm wants j to go above n.

Comment: What's the expected answer?

Comment: Expected Answer: Q (3 rows, 2 columns) =
0.7071068, 0.5773503,
0.0000000, 0.5773503,
-0.7071068, 0.5773503

R (2 rows, 2 columns) = 1.414214 ,-1.414214 ,0.000000 , 5.196152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
txtMGS <- function (A) 
{
  stopifnot(is.numeric(A), is.matrix(A))
  m <- nrow(A)
  n <- ncol(A)
  if (m < n) 
    stop("No. of rows of 'A' must be greater or equal no. of columns.")
  V <- A
  Q <- matrix(0, m, n)
  R <- matrix(0, n, n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    R[i, i] <- sqrt(c(crossprod(V[, i])))
    Q[, i] <- V[, i] / R[i, i]
    if (i < n) {         # <---------------- here is the important addition
      for (j in (i+1):n) {  
        R[i, j] <- sum(Q[, i] * V[, j])
        V[, j] <- V[, j] - R[i, j] * Q[, i]
      }
    }
  }
  return(list(Q = Q, R = R))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, I was able to get my code working.